# Can I change an NSDictionary's key?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dictionary, foundation

I have an `NSDictionary` object that is populated by instances of `NSMutableString` for its keys and objects. I have been able to change the key by changing the original `NSMutableString` with the `setString:` method. They key however remains the same regardless of the contents of the string used to set the key initially.

My question is, is the key protected from being changed meaning it will always be the same unless I remove it and add another to the dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: Never try to mutate a key in a dictionary.  If you do, it's possible that the dictionary will no longer be able to find it.

Comment: Don't do it, ever. Got it. This was part of an exercise to find out if shallow or deep copies were made of a NSDictionary object. I got the answer all right but didn't get what was happening or why with the key. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keys are `-copy`'d when the items are set, so you can't changing it afterwards is useless.

> Methods that add entries to dictionaries—whether as part of initialization (for all dictionaries) or during modification (for mutable dictionaries)—copy each key argument (keys must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol) and add the copies to the dictionary. Each corresponding value object receives a retain message to ensure that it won’t be deallocated before the dictionary is through with it.

You could use CFDictionary with kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, or just replace the item:

```
id value = [dictionary objectWithKey:oldKey];
[dictionary setObject:value withKey:newKey];
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:oldKey];
```

Comment: So what your saying is that the key is immutable regardless of the mutability of the actual collection being mutable or immutable?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `NSMutableDictionary`, instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really an issue for the way I'm using it. Should've said I've tried using both type and that in this case I'm using the mutableCopy copy method and then trying to change the resulting NSMutableDictionary. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a copy of the dictionary, filtering the keys as you go.  I do this for converting between camel-case and underscores when populating objects from JSON using KVC.  See my refactoring library, [es_ios_utils](https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils), for source.  [ESNSCategories.h](https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils/blob/master/es_ios_utils/ESNSCategories.h) provides:

```
@interface NSMutableDictionary(ESUtils)
    //Changes keys using keyFilter. If keyFilter generates duplicate non-unique keys, objects will be overwritten.
    -(void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)d withKeyFilter:(NSString*(^)(NSString*))keyFilter;
...
```

So to make all keys upper case, you could do something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:oldDictionary.count];
[md addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDictionary
               withKeyFilter:^NSString*(NSString *key) { 
                                 return key.uppercaseString;
                             }];
```